# What's the difference between DbContext and ObjectContext

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

From `MSDN`:

> Represents a combination of the Unit-Of-Work and Repository patterns and enables you to query a database and group together changes that will then be written back to the store as a unit. `DbContext` is conceptually similar to `ObjectContext`.

I though `DbContext` only handle the connection to the DB and the number of threads working against the DB.

Now I understand it contains the tracking mechanism? I thought this was in the `ObjectContext`.

So what is (in plain English) the difference between them?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

DbContext is a lightweight version of the ObjectContext class, which is laid almost right on top of ObjectContext (there is even a way to get to the ObjectContext from just the DbContext). It's also a lot easier to use, IMO, and makes CRUD operations a sinch.

For better information, who better to look to than [Julie Lerman](http://thedatafarm.com/data-access/accessing-objectcontext-features-from-ef-4-1-dbcontext/) for more info on the differences, as was brought into EF 4.1.

Comment: check this [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/objectcontext-vs-dbcontext/) for more

Answer (score 6):

the DbContext is a smaller API exposing the most commonly used
features of the ObjectContext. In some cases, those features are mirrored in the DbContext
API. In other cases, the Entity Framework team has simplified more complex coding
by providing us with methods like Find or properties like DbSet.Local. But there’s
a big API lurking underneath that you may still need access to. For example, you might
want to work directly with the MetadataWorkspace to write generic code against classes
because that API can read the model more efficiently than reflection. Additionally, the
MetadataWorkspace is able to provide more information about the metadata than you
can discover with reflection, for example, for Key properties. Or you might want to
take advantage of a database-specific function that is exposed through Entity SQL,
which you can’t access from LINQ to Entities.
Or you may already have an application
written using the ObjectContext and you want to leverage the DbContext in future updates
without replacing all of the ObjectContext code.(Reference from Programming DbContext)

Answer (score 1):

### Object Context:

1.It support compiled query
2.It support self tracking of entities
3.It available for entity frame work 4.0 and below version
4.It is not thread safe.
5.It is best for DB first and model first approach.

### Database Context:

1.It does not support compiled query
2.It support not self tracking of entities
3.It available for entity frame work 4.1 and above version
4.It is thread safe for static and share member(public).
5.It is best for DB first and model first approach and code first approach.