# How do I implement an audit trail using Entity Framework 5?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5

I am trying to implement an audit trail in Entity Framework 5.

```
public class AuditZoneRepository : IAuditZoneRepository
    {
        private AISDbContext context = new AISDbContext();

        public int Save(AuditZone model, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        {
            if (model.Id == 0)
            {
                context.AuditZones.Add(model);
            }
            else
            {
                var recordToUpdate = context.AuditZones.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.Id);
                if (recordToUpdate != null)
                {
                    recordToUpdate.Description = model.Description;
                    recordToUpdate.Valid = model.Valid;
                    recordToUpdate.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }

            try
            {
                context.SaveChanges();
                return 1;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                modelState.AddModelError("", "Database error has occured.  Please try again later");
                return -1;
            }
        }
    }
```

To do so, I need the `ObjectStateEntry` for the `entity`:

```
entities.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(changedEntity);
```

as shown [here](http://xharze.blogspot.com.au/2012/02/how-to-get-changed-properties-for.html).

When I try to add this to the save function it says unknown. What is the entities value in my case?

With Georges help I updated my save code as follows,

```
 public int Save(AuditZone model, ModelStateDictionary modelState)
        {
            if (model.Id == 0)
            {
                context.AuditZones.Add(model);
            }
            else
            {
                var recordToUpdate = context.AuditZones.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.Id);
                if (recordToUpdate != null)
                {
                    recordToUpdate.Description = model.Description;
                    recordToUpdate.Valid = model.Valid;
                    recordToUpdate.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;


                    var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;

                    var entires = objectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(recordToUpdate);

                    IEnumerable<string> modifiedProperties = entires.GetModifiedProperties();
                }
            }

            try
            {




                context.SaveChanges();
                return 1;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                modelState.AddModelError("", "Database error has occured.  Please try again later");
                return -1;
            }
        }
```

but when I debug it the modifiedProperties has no results in it? am I putting this code in the wrong place?

Comment: What is the exact error message? Can you post the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: there is no error messages.. there is no method called AuditZone.ObjectStateManager

Comment: For auditing, you can also override SaveChanges() in DbContext to audit all the changes in an entity. Take a look at: https://auditdbcontext.codeplex.com/

Comment: might look into that thanks lopez..

Answer (score 0):

Taken from the [link](http://xharze.blogspot.com.au/2012/02/how-to-get-changed-properties-for.html) you've posted:

> "we have to use the ObjectStateManager on ObjectContext."

So, `entities` should be an implementation of `ObjectContext`.

To convert `DbContext` to `ObjectContext` use:

```
var objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
```

To get entries use:

```
var entires = objectContext.ObjectStateManager
                           .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Unchanged);
```

More about the `ObjectContext` and its relation with `DbContext`:

- [Entity Framework 4.1 and OriginalValues/CurrentValues and DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002987/entity-framework-4-1-and-originalvalues-currentvalues-and-dbcontext)
- [entity framework 4.1 objectContext vs dbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5376368/entity-framework-4-1-objectcontext-vs-dbcontext)
- [What's the difference between DbContext and ObjectContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14857915/whats-the-difference-between-dbcontext-and-objectcontext)

Comment: george - thanks for that, I updated my code, still having an issue